# How to change the gap between icon and text?

Tags: android, material-design, android-tablayout

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YgdHK.jpg)

To see the picture , please click the link at the top.

Here is a ViewPager + TabLayout。

I use the following code to create the tablayout.

```
firstTab.setIcon(R.drawable.tab_home_green).setText("HOME");
secondTab.setIcon(R.drawable.tab_explore_grey).setText("EXPLORE");
thirdTab.setIcon(R.drawable.tab_me_grey).setText("MIME");
```

1. Now the gap between icon and title is fixed, In the source the gap is private. I want to know how to change the gap value?
2. How to change the padding of each Tab?

Comment: create custom tab's layout...

Comment: better to take icon with text.

Comment: I need two types of view when the tab is selected or not. I tried custom tab but when I click the tab, the view didn't change

Answer (score 0):

Create and inflate a custom tab's layout.

Comment: But I need two type when the tab is selected or not. I tried custom tab but when I click the tab, the view didn't change.

Comment: You can accomplish it with a custom layout as well. Just attach an onTabChanged listener and change the layout of the selected tab.

Answer (score -1):

You can also use view tag in xml for the space between the  icon